# C# TPL Update Gridview every second

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a datagridview which I need to refresh every second from the database. I have written this code so that my UI does not freeze and data fetching operation run in background, but still it freezes / lags my UI. I need your expertise to let me know what mistake I am doing here.

I have a master form from where I am calling the form named Symbols.

```
Symbols childForm1 = new Symbols();
childForm1.MdiParent = this;
this.SplitContainer2.Panel1.Controls.Add(childForm1);
childForm1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
childForm1.Show();
```

Code in Symbols Form -->

```
public DataSet Result { get { return (DataSet)this.dataGridView1.DataSource; } set { this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value.Tables[0]; } }

private Task<DataSet> StartBackgroundWork()
    {
    return new WorkItem().DoWork();
    }
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer MyTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    MyTimer.Interval = (1000);
MTimer.Tick += MyTimer_Tick;
MyTimer.Start();
    }
private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.StartBackgroundWork()
                             .ContinueWith((t) => this.Result = t.Result, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); ;
    }
public class WorkItem
{
    public Task<DataSet> DoWork()
    {
    return Task.Factory.StartNew<DataSet>(this.PerformWork);
    }

    private DataSet PerformWork()
    {
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    ServiceReference1.tblOrder obj = new ServiceReference1.tblOrder();
    obj.order_id = login.client_id;
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client objService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    dt = objService.symboldata(obj);
    return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: How large is the collection that is being bound to your grid? It might be that the lag is due to the UI rendering.

Comment: Every second is probably too frequent if you have large data.

Comment: Data being fetched is not that large. only 20 - 25 rows...but they need to be fetched every second in order to get the updated data. Please suggest the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use **BackgroundWorker** class for avoid freezing of ui.